# Get frame from live video stream

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264, 3gp

I am streaming live video from my camera on my android phone to my computer using the MediaRecorder class.

```
recorder.setCamera(mCamera);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);          
recorder.setOutputFile(uav_UDP_Client.pfd.getFileDescriptor());                     
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

That's the basic idea. So I would like to show this stream in real time. My plan is to use FFMpeg to turn the latest frame into a .bmp and show the .bmp on my C# program every time there is a new frame.

The problem is there is no header until I stop the recording. So I can not use FFMpeg unless there is a header. I've looked at spydroid and using RTP but I do not want to use this method for various reasons.

Any ideas on how I can do this easily?

Comment: You got any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You can consider streaming a `MPEG2 TS` and playing it back on your screen or you can also stream `H.264` data over `RTP` and use a client to decode and display the same.

In Android, there is a sample executable which performs `RTP` packetization of `H.264` stream and streams it over the network. You can find more details about the `MyTransmitter` from this [file](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/rtsp/MyTransmitter.h), which could serve as a good reference to your solution.

**Additional Information**
In Android 4.2.0 release onwards, there is a similar feature supported by the framework called `Miracast` or `Wi-Fi Display` which is standardized by `Wi-Fi` forum, which is a slightly complex use-case.